# Duplicating courses with Moodle webservice with included role enrolments

Tags: web-services, moodle-api

I'm duplicating moodle courses via webservice core_course_duplicate_course. While including role enrolments in the duplicate is easy through UI (see screenshot attached). How can I pass the option for role enrolment in webservice? I want to include only some roleids. I tried to pass the roleids like this, but it didn't work, probably its the wrong key:

```
'options[1][name]' => 'enrolments',
'options[1][value]' => [10, 11],
```

Since I'm new to REST API of moodle, any help is much appreciated!

[image]

```
#!/bin/bash
API="http://10.1.1.13/sm/webservice/rest/server.php"    # WS entry point.
COURSEID=25                                             # Course to duplicated.
CATEGORYID=1                                            # Category to duplicate to.
TOKEN="490b48f8cd71e88a37fa70cc6eff3fb2"                # WS Token.
# SCRIPT STARTS HERE.
SUFFIX=`date +"%s"`
echo "Duplicate with user data"
SHORTNAME="Duplicated${COURSEID}_${SUFFIX}"
curl $API\
    -d moodlewsrestformat=json\
    -d wstoken=$TOKEN\
    -d wsfunction=core_course_duplicate_course\
    -d courseid=$COURSEID\
    -d fullname="Duplicated $COURSEID (with user data) - $SUFFIX"\
    -d shortname="$SHORTNAME"\
    -d categoryid=$CATEGORYID\
    -d 'options[0][name]=users'\
    -d 'options[0][value]=1'
echo
```